# ManyToOne relation with Doctrine against Domain Driven Design

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine, domain-driven-design

I'm facing to an issue with Doctrine relation and DDD.

I already searched a lot but I didn't find a suitable answer.

Let's take a simple example:

I have an aggregate `Category` and an aggregate `Product`.
I would like to have a `ManyToOne` relation between `Product` and `Category`.

Unfortunately Doctrine makes me add an attribute `$category` in my `Product`. But as Vaughn Vernon said, aggregate should reference to other aggregate by his identity, not by the aggregate itself.

Moreover even if I do this, Doctrine overwrites `category_id` to `null` if I don't set `$category`.

My only solution, at this moment, it's to add category_id field in mapping definition and add foreign key by myself.

Is there any other solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you maybe trying to use the wrong tool for the job.  Doctrine 2 is an Object Relational Manager hence it focuses on objects.  If you read through the [docs](https://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#) you won't find very much on domain driven design.

Given that Doctrine focuses on objects then:

```
$category = $product->getCategory();
```

Makes perfect sense.  It also maps nicely onto how sql is designed to work.

If you really want a property Product::CategoryId then go ahead and add it.  The latest Doctrine even has limited support for value objects.

But if you then want to somehow access the actual category object then you will need to add in your own query somehow.  Kind of makes the orm code pretty much useless as you would be handing your own relations.  Maybe drop down to pdo or the database access layer.

I have seen a few articles trying to do what you want but they barely manage the simplest cases and are impractical for any kind of production scenarios.  Especially since DDD implies complex business logic.

Comment: Seems legit. Like Verraes [says](http://verraes.net/2013/12/related-entities-vs-child-entities/), it's all about trade-off. There is no only one solution. Each have benefits and drawbacks I guess. I will add the doctrine relation. We just have to be careful to not edit the object inside `Product`. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I just would add a property `categoryId` to `Product` and that's it.

So I can't navigate from `Product` to `Category` directly, but instead I would need the `CategoryRepository` to fetch the respective category object, if I need it.

I lose the lazy loading convenience, but the aggregates are separated clean and nice.